# jQuery calculate order subtotal. My result gives me the same subtotal for all my rows

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having a little issue with a jquery function. I'm trying to calculate the subtotal given the price and while entering the number for quantity.

Here is my html snippet:

```
<!-- Price -->
<td width="10%"><div class="price" value="0"></div></td>

<!-- Quantity -->
<td width="9%"><input class="quantity" type="text" value="0" size="1" onchange="updateTotal(this)"/></td>

<!-- Subtotal -->
<td width="5%"><div class="subtotal" value="0"></div></td>
```

And my jQuery function:

```
function updateTotal(qty){

//Calculate Subtotal for each item
var quantity = $(qty).val();
var price = $('.price').html();
var subtotal = parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity);
$('.subtotal').text(subtotal);

//Calculate Grand Total
var sum = 0;
$('.subtotal').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
});
$('#grandTotal').html(sum);
```

}

My result:

```
!(http://i45.tinypic.com/16a7exy.png)
!(http://i48.tinypic.com/5vu9uf.png)
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on, I tried to get just the row I was working with but I failed at that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

$('.subtotal').text(subtotal); has an implied .each in it. This is causing you to overwrite every .subtotal row. Make it explicit by replacing that line with:

```
$('.subtotal').each(function(){
this.text(subtotal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
$("#textbox").focusout(function () {
    updateTotal(value);

});
```

Use Jquery and Get the value from the text field, When the focus is out so function is called only once. Onchange is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

2 things if you are working through `.html` then see here: http://jsfiddle.net/UpGWP/

other wise use `.prop` api or `.attr` api to get the value attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/764J8/

hope it helps the need!

Also I have removed `href` from the div `:)`

**code**

```
function updateTotal(qty) {

    //Calculate Subtotal for each item
    var quantity = $(qty).val();
    var price = $('.price').attr('value');
    alert(price);
    var subtotal = parseFloat(price) * parseInt(quantity);
    $('.subtotal').text(subtotal);

    //Calculate Grand Total
    var sum = 0;
    $('.subtotal').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $('#grandTotal').html(sum);
}​
```

Comment: thanks! this seems more cleaner than the roundabout way that I did it